# JQuery и вычисляемая ширина блоков

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Никак не могу сообразить, как сделать, чтобы посадить по горизонтали блоки. Есть html

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

и стили

```
.left,right {float:left;
width:50%;height:10px}
.center {float:left;width:30px;height:10px;}
```

Как JQuery сделать, чтобы правый и левый блок были "чуть меньше" 50% (за вычитом 30px центра), чтобы полностью влезали по ширине окна браузера на разных разрешениях?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
.left {float:left; width: 50%; padding-right: -25px; height:10px} 
.right {float:right; width: 50%;height:10px} 
.center {width:30px;height:10px;margin: 0 auto}
.inside-left{
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.inside-right{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left"><div class="inside-left"></div></div>
<div class="right"><div class="inside-right"></div></div>
<div class="center"></div>
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/t7zL6cxj/

Comment: Спасибо. Даже без JQuery. Для себя немного переделал, ибо сваливалось все равно:
.left {float:left; width: 50%; padding-left: -30px; height:10px} 

Кстати, если мне не изменяет память отрицательных padding быть не может :)

Comment: а он и не нужен: случайно скопировал эксперимент

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/zcdne3av/), самый обычный и простой, я бы сказал:

**HTML** (честно скопипастил у [[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)](/users/4058/deonis)):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="center">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper div { 
    position: absolute; 
    text-align:center; 
}
.left { 
    background: #C7E3E4; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 50%; 
    margin-right: 100px; 
}
.center { 
    background: #E0D2C7; 
    width: 200px; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -100px; 
}
.right { 
    background: #ECD5DE; 
    left: 50%; 
    right: 0; 
    margin-left: 100px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если есть обертка или можно её добавить, то [можно сделать так](http://jsfiddle.net/6vyxqnu9/):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.wrapper > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 10px;
}
.center {
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что при таком варианте левая и правая колонки будут зависеть от контента и могут легко стать 70% и 30%, например.

Comment: @MasterAlex, нет, тут ключевое свойство **table-layout: fixed;**. [Пример][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/6vyxqnu9/1/

Comment: хм, а в примере пишут 50% зачем-то, интересная штука, пригодится в таблицах админки сайта